# Fetch User Profile Picture from new Facebook sdk 4 in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, permissions, profile-picture

I am developing an App in Which I have implemented Facebook now I want to fetch Facebook user profile picture and Birthday in my app. I searched into net but all tutorials are 2 or 3 years old.

I have set permission like..

```
 loginButton.readPermissions=@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends",@"user_birthday",@"user_location"];
```

and fetching with codes

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
            [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
             startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result); 
}
```

but the output is

```
  fetched user:{
email = "XYZ@gmail.com";
"first_name" = XYZ;
gender = male;
id = xxxxxxxxxxx;
"last_name" = ABC;
link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/xxxxxxxxx/";
locale = "en_GB";
name = "XYZ ABC";
timezone = "5.5";
"updated_time" = "2015-04-08T06:57:20+0000";
verified = 1;
```

}

Why i not getting birthday and profile picture information?

Comment: i had tried with parameters but it didnt worked for me.

Comment: should i have to create custom login button for fb login??

Comment: `loginButton.readPermissions=@[@"email"]; `  and `[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday"}]` and use latest Facebook sdk

Comment: solution worked or not?

Comment: no, i have tried with many ways but not getting profile pic

Comment: from this code I am getting the link of profile picture

Answer (score 0):

As Ashish mentioned, `initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil` does not return the profile_pic (or birthday) unless explicitly requested through `initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"picture, birthday"}`

Be careful though, when parameters are not nil, it only returns the requested fields, so you won't get name, gender, etc unless you add them to the parameters explicitly as well